# How to get jquery returned value to a property of model object in Razor Page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to make a selection of multiple items and pass results to an object that has property called SelectedDays

```
<div>
    <select id="daySelector" size="7" multiple="multiple" asp-for="ScheduledTask.SelectedDays"
            asp-validation-for="ScheduledTask.SelectedDays" class="form-control">

        <option value="1">Monday</option>
        <option value="2">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="3">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="4">Thursday</option>
        <option value="5">Friday</option>
        <option value="6">Saturday</option>
        <option value="0">Sunday</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

I am using JQuery to get selected items

```
$("#daySelector").change(function () {
    var arr = $(this).val();
    var result = arr.toString();

    console.log(result);

    return result;
     
})
```

JQuery correctly displays values selected but SelectedDays property passes only one item from selection list.

Comment: What's the type of `SelectedDays`?And which way do you want to pass the selectlist?Just submit form or ajax?

Comment: SelectedDays is type of string. It should be in this format "0,1,2" etc.. I have submit button (type="submit") that does post method. Object ScheduledTask is validated and saved in a database. This is really new to me, so maybe I'm not approaching this correctly

Comment: Hi @tipitoe,check my answer below.The main problem is that you set the wrong type of the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,you need define the property as type `List<T>`.

Secondly,not sure how did you get the `ScheduledTask` object,but if you get the object by parameter,you need use `[Bind(Prefix = "ScheduledTask")]` to specify the suffix,because the name of the select is `ScheduledTask.SelectedDays`.

Here is the working demo:

Model:

```
public class ScheduledTask
{
    public List<string> SelectedDays { get; set; }
}
```

cshtml.cs(You could use `BindProperty` to auto get the data from frontend):

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public ScheduledTask ScheduledTask { get; set; }
    public void OnPost()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Another way:**

cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public ScheduledTask ScheduledTask { get; set; }
    public void OnPost([Bind(Prefix = "ScheduledTask")]ScheduledTask model)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

If you do not want to change the model property type,you could custom model binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;

        // Try to fetch the value of the argument by name
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
        string combindedString = string.Join(",", valueProviderResult.ToArray());

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        // Check if the argument value is null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(combindedString))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(combindedString);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class ScheduledTask
{
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))]
    public string SelectedDays { get; set; }
}
```

And be sure specify the name(add `name="SelectedDays"`):

```
    <select id="daySelector" size="7" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedDays" asp-for="ScheduledTask.SelectedDays"
        asp-validation-for="ScheduledTask.SelectedDays"
        class="form-control">

    <option value="1">Monday</option>
    //...
</select>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I Have {BindProperty] set already for object ScheduledTask. All I had to do is to change type from string to List<string> for property SelectedDays